# How to raise an error if a select query returns rows

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a view that returns 'bad' rows. I would like a procedure to raise an exception if the view returns any records. I will call this from an external program. How can this be implemented? Pseudo code follows:

```
create procedure pr_bad_records_check()
language sql
as
$$
if 
    select count(*) from vw_my_bad_records > 0
then 
    raise error 'some bad rows were found, run select * from vw_my_bad_records for details'
end if
$$;
```

Comment: You really need to be more specific as to what you consider a bad row to be, because if you can describe it then you should be able to filter them out.

Comment: I have a big heap of warehousing code that depends on certain data consistencies / assumptions being true on a bunch of incoming records. If these assumptions are not met, the warehousing code should not run. I want therefore to raise an exception to the calling load process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know there is an accepted answer, but let me show you another approach. 
You won't need to declare any variables since you can use the special variable `FOUND`. 
Also, would be better to add a `LIMIT` clause to your select, since one row is enough to throw the exception:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pr_bad_records_check() RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN 
  PERFORM * FROM vw_my_bad_records LIMIT 1;
  IF FOUND THEN 
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'some bad rows were found, run select * from vw_my_bad_records for details'; 
  END IF; 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1):

PLpgSQL allows to use SQL queries inside a expressions. So your task can to have a easy, readable and fast solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pr_bad_records_check()
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM vw_my_bad_records) THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION
       USING MESSAGE='some bad rows were found',
             HINT='Run select * from vw_my_bad_records for details.';
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```